# Sticky div using jquery in react

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to use jquery in react to create a sticky header but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Here is my code. I would really appreciate the help. I have been stuck for hours trying to figure this out. I tried to use react-sticky but it always disappears when you scroll to far plus I really want to work on my jquery skills. I tried to add jquery through webpack and the index.

index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/reset.css"/>
       <title>Portfolio Site</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src='/scripts/bundle.js'></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This is my Projects.jsx code.

```
     import React from 'react';
     import $ from 'jquery';

     import ProjectsHeader from './ProjectsHeader.jsx';

     export default class Projects extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
        super()
       }

      render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <section className="projects-background"></section>
              <ProjectsHeader/>
              <div className="demo-space"></div>
            </div>
           )
          }
         }
```

This is my webpack.config.js code.

```
          module.exports = {
            entry: {
            main: './public/app/PortfolioApp.jsx'
           },
           output: {
             filename: 'bundle.js',
             path: './public/scripts'
           },
           devtool: 'sourcemap',
           module: {
             loaders: [{
               test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
               exclude: /node_modules/,
               loader: 'babel'
            }, {
               test: /\.s?css$/,
               exclude: /node_modules/,
               loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
             }]
             new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: "jquery",
                jQuery: "jquery"
              })
             }
            };
```

This is my Projects.scss code.

```
       body{
         padding-top:350px;
       }

       .projects-background{
           top: 0;
           height: 100vh;
           width: 100vw;
           background-image: url(/img/code.jpeg);
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-size: cover;
           position: fixed;
        }

        .demo-space{
            height: 200vh;
            width:100vw;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .header{
            top: 0;
            height: 15vh;
            width: 100vw;
            background-color: black;
            opacity: 0.9;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            z-index: 1;
            span{
              height: 100vh;
              width: 33.33%;
            }
          }

          .sticky{
             position: fixed;
          }
```

ProjectsHeader.jsx component code

```
   import React from 'react';
   import jQuery from 'jquery';
   import $ from 'jquery';

 export default class ProjectsHeader extends React.Component{

   constructor(){
   super()
  }

  componentDidMount(){
     var head = $(".header");
     var stick = $(".sticky");
      $(window).scroll(function(){
      $(this).scrollTop() > 350
         ?head.addClass(stick)
         :head.removeClass(stick)
      })
    }

  render(){
     return(
       <div className="header">
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
       </div>
     )
    }
   }
```

Comment: Could you share the code of the `ProjectsHeader` component?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: I just added the component code. I'm not getting any errors in the console or webpack.

Comment: I got rid of the sticky and was trying to do a manual sticky nav. I' ll edit that from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:
`var stick = $(".sticky");`
should be this:
`var stick = "sticky";`

At least in jQuery syntax.

`$(".sticky");` returns an array of jQuery objects that match the `.sticky` class selector. What you want is a string representation of the class name, hence `"sticky"`

**The next problem** is the reference `$(this)`  -- that won't work (it returns the react class constructor). You'll need a valid jQuery selector here, like a class or ID

Like so:

```
componentDidMount(){

 var head = $(".header");
 var stick = ".sticky";

 $(window).scroll(function(){
  $('.scrollingElementClass').scrollTop() > 350
     ? head.addClass(stick)
     : head.removeClass(stick)
  })
}
```

Comment: I created it to look like this but it still isn't becoming sticky. I tried both var stick = "sticky"; and var stick = ".sticky";. Neither one seems to work.

Comment: componentDidMount() {

  var head = $(".header");
  var stick = "sticky";

  $(window).scroll(function() {
   $('.scrollingElementid').scrollTop() > 350
    ? head.addClass(stick)
    : head.removeClass(stick)
  })
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <div id='scrollingElementid' className="header">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
   </div>
  )
 }
}
This is the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by doing this:

```
componentDidMount() {

    var head = $(".header");
    var stick = "sticky";

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $(window).scrollTop() > 350
            ? head.addClass(stick)
            : head.removeClass(stick)
    })
}
```

Comment: Excellent :) Glad you got it going.

Comment: Thank you for your help.